# Android: Get details from php script with htaccess and htpasswd

Tags: php, android, .htaccess

I have a php script with this output:
[image]

And then I display this data in Android. But now, I put a `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file in the directory and I have to enter a password, if I want to read the data. My question is how can I display the data in Android, now with the files (`.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`). Is there a way to enter the password in Android to show the data because now I cant display the data..
Thanks

EDIT:

This is my php script:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["feed"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $feed = array();
        $feed["uid"] = $row["uid"];
        $feed["unique_id"] = $row["unique_id"];
        $feed["name"] = $row["name"];
        $feed["full_name"] = $row["full_name"];
        $feed["email"] = $row["email"];
        $feed["age"] = $row["age"];
        $feed["about_the_customer"] = $row["about_the_customer"];
        $feed["encrypted_password"] = $row["encrypted_password"];
        $feed["salt"] = $row["salt"];
        $feed["created_at"] = strtotime($row["created_at"]);
        $feed["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        $feed["imageName"] = $row["imageName"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["feed"], $feed);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No feed found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using basic authentication for this?

Comment: I don't want that everybody can see this output, if they search for the url. I only want that the data display on android

Comment: Try security through obscurity. Make the URL a random file name.  and Maybe use a api type call. Have Android use a generated key and if that key matches in the php/config script, then return the data. Otherwise, it won't return anything. Use more security in your script. e.g. `example.com/somescript.php?key=123456789`

Comment: can you have a look at my php script and explain what do you mean by "more security"? :-)

Comment: [Please don't include screenshots of code or error messages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/616644). Among other problems, it makes it hard for people to search for it later.